# AngularJS Getting Setting more than one controller

Tags: angularjs, architecture, controllers, firebase

I am new to AngularJS with FireBase as my data store. I have gone through the examples on their website. Now, I would like to expand on the simple concepts and create a more detailed application.

Let's say, for example, I have a recipe controller. This would contain the recipe name and a short description. But, I also want to have a list of ingredients along with their quantities.

The ingredients would be a select element with a list of available ingredients to choose from.

My question is, how do I utilize multiple controllers on a CRUD site? Or should I not use multiple controllers and somehow use the recipe controller to handle everything?

If I were doing this by creating the database schema in, say, MSSQL I would have no problem and would know exactly what to do. I think it's the fact that everything is client-side that is throwing me off.

Thanks in advance for any assistance provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably won't want to have a controller per entity. You're controller here maps to a scope object. The scope is then bound to a view - keeping them in sync.

So if your view displays a recipe (i.e name/description), it might also have a child property ingredients ($scope.recipe.ingredients).

You're controller will manage this 'recipe' object, and also provide methods to modify/retrieve/manage it. Say for example you want to save the $scope.reciepe object to your FireBase store - you can inject a service into your controller, and then make a $http call to 'put' that object into your db.

A brief conceptual overview of control

See more at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: To restate in different words, it is often more useful to have a controller per view, rather than a controller per model. If you then want to modularize model-specific functions for different models that are used in the same view, you might consider creating a service for each model. This is just one possible pattern though.

Comment: Also, you can utilize [angularFire](http://github.com/firebase/angularfire) to automagically inject data into Firebase and skip the $http REST commands.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks leon. That was just the clarification I needed. Kato, yes I will be utilizing angularFire for certain.